# Unchecked runtime.lastError while running input.ime.sendKeyEvents: Engine is not available

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this code:

```
let ime_api = chrome.input.ime;

export const sendKey = (options, cb = null) => {
    return ime_api.sendKeyEvents(options, cb);
};

export const sendSpaceKey =  (cb) => {
    sendKey({
        contextID: 0,
        keyData: [{
            type: 'keydown',
            requestId: 'fewfavoihifgyiurhs',
            key: ' ',
            code: 'Space',
        },{
            type: 'keyup',
            requestId: 'gjsghgusyrurgfkeufygsfr',
            key: ' ',
            code: 'Space',
        }]
    }, cb);
};

sendSpaceKey(() => console.log('Space clicked'));
```

My manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",    
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*/*" ],
      "js": [ "app/content.js" ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "input", "tabs", "storage", "activeTab", "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["app/background.js"]
  },
  "input_components": [
    {
      "name": "Test IME",
      "type": "ime",
      "id": "test",
      "description": "Test IME",
      "language": "en-US",
      "layouts": ["us::eng"]
    }
  ]

}
```

Chrome return me:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running input.ime.sendKeyEvents: Engine is not available

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHp9D.png)

Why?

P.S. [Google chrome extension input.ime api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime#method-sendKeyEvents)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this while trying to develop an extension for Chrome on Windows. Apparently the input.ime API is only for Chrome OS.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/input_ime

It's at the top.